# Avoid items from ViewTree onScrollChanged()

Tags: android, scrollview, android-viewtreeobserver, onscrollchanged

I am using `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener` to determine when `ScrollView` bottom has been reached.

Here is my layout:

```
<ScrollView>

 <RelativeLayout>

  <FrameLayout>//use as a banner       
  </FrameLayout>

  <RelativeLayout>//there are some other views inside this layout
  </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am programatically adding a `ViewPager` to `FrameLayout` in `ScrollView` and it has timer to change the page periodically.

Since

> `onScrollChanged()` is a callback method to be invoked when something
>   in the view tree has been scrolled.

`onScrollChanged()` is calling every time when `ViewPager`'s page changed.

I **ONLY** need to work `onScrollChanged()` when I scrolling the `ScrollView`. Is there anyway to achieve this?

PS: I can't put `FrameLayout(ViewPager)` outside of the `ScrollView`.